# django project on apache2 + mod_wsgi - TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django

I just installed mod_wsgi on server with apache2.
I also installed django.

I created project and app inside project (in fact I uploaded app from my local machine).

The url-view mapping in my app works but when view tries to render any template there is TemplateDoesNotExist exception.

All my templates are in /[project]/[app]/templates/[app] (there are also some sub directories in this directory such "elements" and "errors" with specific templates)

Anyway it seems that django/wsgi doesn see the templates in my app - on my local machine {with django developement server) it works ok and django finds templates in my [app]/templates directory.

I am render templates using this path "[app]/base.html" or "[app]/elements/some_elements.html"

in my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /var/src/[project]/[project]/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/src/[project]/

<Directory /var/src/[project]>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does apache have read permission on the templates?

Comment: Make sure you haven't used relative path names in configuration. The current working directory under Apache will not be where the project is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py pointing at the correct location for this server?

Comment: No - I think template loader should find it in my app - I dont want to add some extra configuration to my project. The debug message says "Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:" - so it should find it in my app, shouldnt it? even in django tutorial there is that its enough to put templates in app/templates/app dir...